# bad uid 8 in virtual_uid_maps

Tags: linux, postfix, gentoo, uid

Sending mail fails. Logs show this error:

```
warning: recipient user@domain.com: bad uid 8 in virtual_uid_maps
```

Relevant settings in main.cf:

```
local_recipient_maps =
virtual_uid_maps = static:8
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
transport_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/transport.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/mailboxes.cf
virtual_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql/virtual.cf
```

/var/spool/mail is owned by mail:mail:

```
root@gentooserver ~ # ls -la /var/spool/mail
total 4
drwxrwsr-t 1 mail mail 92 Apr 11 19:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 68 Nov 29 17:05 ..
-rw------- 1 mail mail 31 Apr 11 18:51 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 mail mail  0 Nov 29 17:05 .keep_net-mail_mailbase-0
drwx--S--- 1 mail mail 18 Apr 11 19:00 .maildir
```

mail has a UID of 8:

```
root@gentooserver ~ # cat /etc/passwd | grep mail
nullmail:x:88:88:added by portage for nullmailer:/var/spool/nullmailer:/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:12:added by portage for mailbase:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
postmaster:x:14:232:added by portage for mailbase:/var/spool/mail:/sbin/nologin
```

What's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"virtual_minium_uid" needs to be set to a value equal or lower than "virtual_uid_maps".